# Save Conversation History by using Exchange Web Service [ EWS ] Lync Client SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchange-server, lync, lync-client-sdk

I am creating one sample asp.net web application by using Lync Client SDK-2013, i want to save chat history between lync users. By searching in net i found out that from Exchange Web Service [EWS] we can save chat history but how to start EWS i have no idea. I want to know how to save Conversation by using EWS. Other than EWS any other mechanism is there to save conversation history by using Lync Client SDK??

Answer (score 0):

> > want to know how to save Conversation by using EWS

There is a pretty comprehensive sample and explanation for doing this using EWS  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh243707(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Thanks for answering.But Is there any other mechanism to save lync conversation history by using Lync client SDK-2013??

Comment: AFAIK no the lync SDK is focused around accessing lync, the conversation history data is stored in Exchange so you will need to use an Exchange API to access that data (which is what the lync clients do). Its pretty easy to use the EWS Managed API